# Java Spring mvc schemaLocation causes 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Looking at implementing a very basic java spring application. Currently I am attempting to include the js/css files on a view. When I add the necessary information in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file under schemaLocation my site throws a 404 error.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
--breaks things http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
--breaks things  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pkg"/>
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

pom.xml dependency call

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

view

```
 <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/file.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Try removing the slash in the front.

Comment: What slash are you referring to?

Comment: The slash '/' in the mapping and value attributes in mvc:resources tag

Comment: I tried all combinations of slashes in that line.. Still recieve a 404 error from the browser. But nothing useful in the tomcat console. The 404 is thrown when I add the schema/mvc urls in the schemaLocation.

Comment: I think you are on the right track though. After I removed the <mvc:resource> line the page loaded. Let me play around with that to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Did you also remove slash in front of resources in view as well?

Comment: Yeah I tried that :/